# How to get time since frame start in Unity for loading purposes

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, frame-rate, milliseconds

I am building a big world (1000+ game objects). It takes 2s on the device. I am doing it in the background (the world is hidden until fully loaded). I have figured out that I can maintain the FPS of the active scene by switching to coroutines and making `yield return null;`.

The main issue is when to fire `yield return null;`. If I do it too often, then it will slow down the loading. If I do it too rarely, it will reduce FPS on low-end devices.

My idea is simple to detect how much milliseconds have passed since the start of the frame and fire `yield return null;` just after I have spent for example 12ms (to leave some time to render everything else and maintain something near 60FPS).

However, I can not find an efficient way of getting the time since frame start? Unity should have something as the async loading of assets seems to consume just right time to maintain stable FPS.

Comment: Why not load your scenes async? Theres a callback when the scene is ready and it fixes the "slows down the loading" part of your problem.

Comment: I am doing it already. However, a lot of work only can be done after the scene finished loading and activated. We have a lot of objects which are instantiated manually and a lot of custom backing work. We have done it in on Start until now, but it was the worst decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory) has given the [great and right answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154630/33648) on [GameDev StackExchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/154630/33648).

Answer (score 0):

You can use and assign Time.time to some variable (example lastFrameTime) and in next frame check if Time.time - lastFrameTime > amountOfTimeToRefresh...

Or Time.delta time assign to lastFrameTime and do the same if...

and if that condition is true do whatever you want and reset lastFrameTime to 0

Hope it helps...

Comment: This will not work. Time.time is the float and do not have enough granularity to detect such tiny intervals.